# JavaScript: Multi-Line Selection on <textarea> field

Tags: javascript, firefox

Hellow,

Mozilla's Firefox Browser allows doing multi-line selections on the default HTML `<textarea>` field, using the common way by pressing CTRL while selecting some text using the mouse.

My question: Is it possible to receive the respective selection data?

I already tried using the `getSelection()` method on the global `window` object, but this contains just nothing. The `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties on the `HTMLTextAreaElement` itself also just contains the last selection made and I also didn't found any other - may Firefox own - attributes or functions which allows me to get access to them.

Of course, it is also possible to create an own listener using the `select` event on the respective `<textarea>` field. However, I guess this is a horrible idea and leads to incorrect information if not all possible procedures, which manipulates or changes the selections in any way, are really covered and on track.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

First you get the whole value of the textarea. Then you take the substring between the selectionStart and selectionEnd - which is the selected portion of the content.

```js
// Create a reference to the textarea object for simpler code after this
var textarea = document.getElementById('textareaId');
// Get the part of the value that is selected
var selected = textarea.value.substring(textarea.selectionStart,
    textarea.selectionEnd);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not what I meant. The selectionStart and SelectionEnd properties does only contain one single selection area. But, since Firefox allows doing more than one selection in a <textarea> field (by pressing CTRL while selecting), I want to receive all made selection areas.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense